# Hg-Git and the Current Version (2) of Mercurial?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, github, hg-git

Any compatibility or stability issues with using Hg-Git with version 2 of Mercurial? I am tempted to use Hg-Git to allow me to use Hg but use Github as my repository. Most web chatter about both seems to be about earlier versions. Any current stability or compatibility concerns?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for those who rushed into close this, this is exactly what I was searching for. Overzealous much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn’t hear of any... Does that answer your question? :)

You should check out the [hg-git mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/hg-git). Looks like there were some troubles with 1.9 but they were fixed, and no reports of issues with 2.0.

Contrary to what the version number may suggest, Mercurial 2.0 hasn’t got more changes than usual compared to 1.9, so it isn’t unexpected that the extension would still work fine without change.

I notice the [hg-git homepage](http://hg-git.github.com/) doesn’t mention Mercurial 2.0; it probably wasn’t updated yet, you could mail Augie Fackler a reminder note.